# Windows 7 Does not recognize 12 monitors

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I'm setting up a monitor wall with 12 screens, using 1 AMD HD 4350 (dual DVI), 1 AMD 2350 (one DVI and one VGA) and eight USB-to-VGA adapters, with 4 of them hooked up to a self-powered USB 3.0 Hub.
I managed to get up to 10 screens working at the same time, but no matter what happens I wasn't able to get the last 2 working. Apparently all of the USB converters are working.

The Machine is running the GPUs mentioned above, with a Core 2 Duo E7500 @ 2.9GHz on 4 GB of RAM. The USB adapter is called "UGA USB Display Adapter".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you connect 11th monitor? Have you checked how many monitors work when only one is connected to GPUs?

Comment: It happens nothing when i connect the 11th monitor. The number of monitors connected to GPUs does not influence the number of monitors recognized. Having anywhere from 0 to 4 makes no difference in the USB connections.

Comment: Have you tested if all USB can be connected at the same time, and 2 of the other screens not, and if that works? You'll have to figure out if its a limitation of having that many through USB (for example a problem with the hub) or that windows somehow does not understand more than 10 screens.

Comment: So you can't connect more than 6 monitors through USB, no matter how many are connected to GPUs? What's the resolution of screens and their refresh rate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit of six USB-connected monitors is imposed by the USB Adapters you're using.

> **How many USB monitors can be supported by a single PC?**
>
> Up to 6 USB displays are supported on a PC, and up to 4 displays on a Mac. Under Windows Multipoint Server, up to 14 USB clients are supported.

http://www.displaylink.com/for-business/common_questions.php